# Google Photos do not keep original size

Tags: google-photos

I've uploaded some photos to Google Photos, having defined in settings to keep original size, but after I've downloaded them, they are smaller.

For example, a photo that has 2.1 MB, after put it in Google Photos and downloaded again, comes with 551.9 KB.

Also tried this, using Google Takeout, and have the same problem.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: How are you uploading them?

Comment: Via browser. At google.com/photos

Answer (score 1):

You should check if there is enough space left on your drive, since Google drive changes the settings to high quality when the space in below 20%.

If that's not the case, this might be due to your connect speed, the drive shows a smaller version if it detects slow speed, however you can open image only in new tab, which would load the original.

Comment: No, I still have 9 gb of space left. I'm with Wi-Fi. Also opening in a new tab it downloads a very smaller version.

Comment: A very strange behavior. When I upload the photos drag and drop them to the browser they are converted. When I upload them choosing from the PC they are not.